# Sending a dictionary to url reverse function in a template

Tags: django

I am using the `{% url .. %}` tag to produce URLs based on views.

Is there anyway I can send a dictionary var to "url", for example:

`{% url myviews param %}`

where param is `{"type" : 1}` (instead of using `{% url myviews type=1 %}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `url` tag does not support a dictionary as an argument.

You could write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) that gives this functionality. This would use the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function. I would look at how the `url` template tag is implemented in [`django.template.defaulttags`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaulttags.py) for reference.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
params = {"type": 1}
reverse("my_view", kwargs=params)
```

Comment: Is there a python django's python function for reversing URLs like in the template tag that I can use?

Comment: Yes, it is `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your template load:

```
{% load url from future %}
<a href="{% url 'my_view' type1=1 type2=2 %}">go</a>
```

You need to have a URL pattern on my_view that can catch the values